# Extracting specific parts of a HTML-File with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom, extract

I've got a HTML-File with several tables from which I try to extract the link and image part. I'm using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

Here's the HTML-File to parse:

```
<h1>Title</h1>
<p>Text</p>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/some_url">
                <img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://google.com/some_image.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Text</p>

<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/this_url">
                <img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://google.com/this_image.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
```

And what I need as an output:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/some_url">
    <img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://google.com/some_image.jpg"/>
</a>

<a href="http://www.google.com/this_url">
    <img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://google.com/this_image.jpg"/>
</a>
```

Here's the PHP part – but doesn't work the way i want it...

```
<?php

// Include the library
include('simple_html_dom.php');

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html('http://google.com');

// Find all images & links
foreach($html->find('img') as $IMGelement)
foreach($html->find('a') as $Aelement)
echo '<a href="' . $Aelement->href . '"><img src="' . $IMGelement->src . '" /><br>';

?>
```

Comment: Where are you using the PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser? I don't see it, looks like HTML. I also don't see a question here about the issue you are having with the parsing.

Comment: Please find the PHP code above. But it's not really working the way i want it...

Comment: Okay, and what happens with the current code vs. what do you want to happen?

Comment: Current code generates a list of every picture with every link. What i want is to extract the link and image only out of each table. In the HTML-Code above commented as "<!-- Output in need: -->".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to find an img within a tag :

```
foreach($html->find('a img') as $IMGelement) {
    echo '<a href="' . $IMGelement->parent()->href . '"><img src="' .$IMGelement->src .'" /><br>';
}
```

Comment: This generates a list of all images, but without the link inside the "a href"-tag...

Comment: @CorruptNetwork $IMGelement->parent()->href show the link very well

Comment: Yes, this works! Thanks a lot! Is there also a way to extract only the images/links within the specific tables? i have a lot of other HTML-stuff in that file i don't need (see HTML above).

Comment: @CorruptNetwork Write a condition to select, I try. By the way, it would be good to accept the answer

Comment: Glad to help! And what about your additions?

Comment: I'm still trying to extract these tables in the HTML File: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr><td>
            <a href="http://www.google.com/this_url">
                <img width="100" height="100" border="0" src="http://google.com/this_image.jpg"/>
            </a>
        </td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

Comment: $html->find('table') - this is full table

Comment: I need to find exactly the table mentioned above, not every table as your solution: <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"> <tbody> <tr><td>  ...

Comment: `find('table[cellspacing=0 and cellpadding=0 and border=0 ]')` try this. I am not sure in `and` but now can't to try. If doesn't work I write tomorrow

Comment: It's not working that way, but if found a workaround by counting the tables i need with: $var1 = $html->find('table', 11); etc. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It is well that you found the solution. Good luck!